# Ansible connect to specific ip

Tags: passwords, ansible

I'm creating an integration tool thal will rely on ansible for some tasks.
One of them is to create users and change passwords on linux servers.

I'm trying to tell ansible to connect to a specific host IP and execute a command.

In a test, this commans works just fine:

```
ansible all -i xx.xx.xx.xx, -m ping
```

Ansile connects to the given IP and executes "ping".
The problem is when I try to use "user" module:

```
ansible all -i xx.xx.xx.xx, -m user "name=aaa update_password=always password='bbb'"
```

I get the error: "ERROR! Missing target hosts"

I've made a lot of atempts with variations and it seems like the momment I put quotes in my command, I always get this error... Putting the IP address between quotes changes nothing.

Any ideas on what is happening?

Thanks.

Comment: What version of ansible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When specifying additional parameters for a module, use the -a flag.

```
Usage: ansible <host-pattern> [options]

Options:
  -a MODULE_ARGS, --args=MODULE_ARGS
                        module arguments
```

Thus, change your command to:

```
ansible all -i xx.xx.xx.xx, -m user -a "name=aaa update_password=always password='bob'"
```

Note, I didn't specifically test this with the user module, but I did confirm the behavior with the debug module by using `anisble all -i xx.xx.xx.xx, -m debug "msg=Hello"` and it failed, then added the -a and it succeeded (I'm using version 2.0.2.0).

Comment: I confirm this solves the problem. Thanyou very much Theo. Just saved my day :)